# Sorry an unexpected error happened! SQL error

Tags: mysql, error-handling

I am new to MYSQL, having trouble with given procedure while executing. It is working perfectyl fine with SQL version 5.7.28 but throwing the following error with SQL 5.6.41

```
ERROR:
SQL query:


create procedure menus_hier_upward
(
in p_menu_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default(0)
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7
```

The procedure I am executing is :

```
create procedure menus_hier_upward
(
in p_menu_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default(0);
declare v_dpth smallint unsigned default(0);

create temporary table hier(
 parent_id smallint unsigned, 
 menu_id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select menu_id, null, v_dpth from menus where menu_id = p_menu_id;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from menus m inner join hier on m.menu_id = hier.parent_id and hier.depth = v_dpth) then

        insert into hier select m.parent_id, m.menu_id, v_dpth + 1 
            from menus m inner join tmp on m.menu_id = tmp.parent_id and tmp.depth = v_dpth;

        set v_dpth = v_dpth + 1;            

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_dpth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select 
-- m.menu_id,
 m.name as menu_name
-- p.menu_id as parent_id,
-- p.name as parent_menu_name,
-- hier.depth
from 
 hier
inner join menus m on hier.menu_id = m.menu_id
left outer join menus p on hier.parent_id = p.menu_id;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end #
```

The server configuration I am using is:

- PHP 7.3
- MYSQL 5.6.41

It would be appreciated if anyone can tell me what's I am doing wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue you are having is with the defining of the program delimiter:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-defining.html

> If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.
>
> To redefine the mysql delimiter, use the delimiter command. The
>   following example shows how to do this for the dorepeat() procedure
>   just shown. The delimiter is changed to // to enable the entire
>   definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then
>   restored to ; before invoking the procedure. This enables the ;
>   delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the
>   server rather than being interpreted by mysql itself.

That means, your code should be:

```
delimiter //

create procedure menus_hier_upward
  (
    in p_menu_id smallint unsigned
  )
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_dpth smallint unsigned default 0;

create temporary table hier(
 parent_id smallint unsigned, 
 menu_id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select menu_id, null, v_dpth from menus where menu_id = p_menu_id;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from menus m inner join hier on m.menu_id = hier.parent_id and hier.depth = v_dpth) then

        insert into hier select m.parent_id, m.menu_id, v_dpth + 1 
            from menus m inner join tmp on m.menu_id = tmp.parent_id and tmp.depth = v_dpth;

        set v_dpth = v_dpth + 1;            

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_dpth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select 
    -- m.menu_id,
    m.name as menu_name
    -- p.menu_id as parent_id,
    -- p.name as parent_menu_name,
    -- hier.depth
from 
  hier
inner join menus m on hier.menu_id = m.menu_id
left outer join menus p on hier.parent_id = p.menu_id;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end //

delimiter ;
```

You can test it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed86e6

Notice the '//' delimiter setting to the right of the `Build Schema` button